# Replacing Claim in a token without authenitcation

Tags: identityserver4

My application connects to different databases based on the choice of the user at login.

At the time of login user is asked for the division and I found the way to include that division id in the token by using the object parameter named extra on tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync method.

Now if the user changes the division I want to replace the division id in token to the new division without asking the user their credentials again.

Its just a change of one claim in the token.

In Essence once the token is being created, is there any way to replace a claim in the token without asking for user credentials again?

Is this possible using extension grants? If not then what is the recommended solution?

Thanks in advance.
Noufal